# Join query include all ship classes with less than N ships

Tags: sql, join

I have the following two tables:

table1: ShipClass(PK class ,type,country,numguns)

table2: Ship(FK class , name,year)

so the ShipClass table contains information about all classes a ship can be

and the Ship table is representing an existing ship.Not all entries in ShipClasses
have entry using the Foreign key "class" in the Ship table.

My goal is to find all the classes that have less than 2 ships(including the classes that don't have a ship !)

I have tried left joining all classes and finding the count:

```
select ShipClasses.CLASS, count(*) as totalShips from ShipClasses
left join Ships
on ShipClasses.CLASS = ships.CLASS
GROUP BY ShipClasses.CLASS
```

The problem I face with this query is that if there is in ShipClasses let's say a  class named "Iowa" and it doesn't have an existing ship in the Ships table then it will show in the result
like this :

Iowa  | 1

this is due to the fact i am using LEFT JOIN , but if I only JOIN then in the result there will be no Iowa, however I want Iowa to appear with totalShips=0 . How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your query will just generate an error that `ShipClasses` is undefined.

Comment: thanks, fixed the query so that an existing table is in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are aggregating by the column in the wrong table:

```
select c.CLASS, count(sc.CLASS) as totalShips
from CLASSES c left join
     ShipClasses s
     on c.CLASS = sc.CLASS
GROUP BY c.CLASS
```

Comment: what's the difference between count(*) and count(sc.CLASS) :?

Comment: @ThomasRothen . . . `COUNT(*)` counts rows.  `COUNT(sc.CLASS)` counts the non-`NULL` values of `sc.CLASS` -- in this case, the number of rows that match the `LEFT JOIN`.